# Creating a Vector of Pointers that each point to a vector that holds ints

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

This code is for C++:

```
vector < int > minValues;
vector < vector < int > * > minValuesPTR;
minValuesPTR.push_back(new minValues);
```

I don't understand why this does not let me compile. I have tried different variations and the only one that lets me compile is this line here:

```
minValuesPTR.push_back(new vector<int>);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `minValues` isn't a type, it's a variable. Did you perhaps mean to use `typedef` to declare it as one?

Comment: ahhh ok. This makes sense. For some reason i just could not wrap my head around it. Thanks guys. Makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

`vector<int> minValues;` is a variable declaration, which you're trying to use as a type.  Perhaps you mean `typedef vector<int> minValues;`?

Answer (score 0):

`minValues` is a vector composed of `int`.  It has a *physical* meaning to your program -- it is not a definition of a class.  As a result, you can not create a new copy of it.